# Again about paging in MVC (Razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've read a lot of articles and answers about paging in MVC.
I've managed to make a search results with paging (using PagedList) but now I need another thing.
I've got a list of genres and based on a genre I want to browse all the albums for that genre.
The url is Home/Browse/1 (id of genre).
How can I page this result because it has already a parameter (genreid) ?
Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to understand how to paginate, I would suggest that you write your own custom paging logic instead of relying on someone else's `PagedList` abstraction.

When you need to paginate results, you need to also include 2 other aspects of the overall query that will be sent to the database: **Filtering**, and **Sorting**.

The reason why is because unless you also apply both sorting and filtering in combination with paging, you will not be able to compute the correct results.

For example, say I have a table of 100 rows and I want to show 10 rows per page. The first 10 rows sorted A-Z will be different than the first 10 rows sorted Z-A. So the table must be sorted before it can be paginated.

Your question has to do with filtering -- you want to filter out all of the albums that are not in a particular genre. Again, this means you must apply filtering before paginating the filtered results.

Ultimately your controller is going to have to hit the database to get the results. You can paginate by sending a filtered and sorted query to the database, then chopping out only a subset to display pagination to the user. However just because you can doesn't mean you should. Ideally, you would like to send the db 1 query that applies filtering, sorting, and pagination to return exactly the paged section you need.

You should be able to do this with a query like the following:

```
// assuming pageNumber is Nullable<int>, and is passed as action method argument
pageNumber = pageNumber ?? 1
var pageSize = 10;
var pageIndex = pageNumber.HasValue ? pageNumber.Value - 1 : 0;
var results = context.Albums
    .Where(a => a.GenreId == genreId) // filtering
    .OrderBy(a => a.GenreId) // sorting
    .Skip(pageSize * pageIndex) // skip this many rows (pagination start at)
    .Take(pageSize) // then give me this many rows (pagination chunk)
    .ToList() // execute the query against the database
;
return view(results);
```

Your view would then have a model type like the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<Album>
```

I assume that from using PagedList and MVC, you already know how to send the pageNumber parameter to the controller / action method. For your filtering URL (Home/Browse/1) you are passing the filtering parameter to the action method already.

If you ever decide you also want to allow the user to sort the results, you must also pass sorting information into the action method parameter. The code above assumes the natural ordering in the database (which will generally be by AlbumId).

Same goes with the pageSize. If you want to make any part of the query (sorting, filtering, pageSize, pageNumber) customizable to the user, you must pass these values as arguments to the action method. Otherwise, the controller will have to use compiled values as in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

Creator of PagedList here. You can do what you're asking like so:

`http://localhost:1234/home/browse/1?page=2`

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public object Browse(int genreId, int? page)
  {
    // the *page* variable is bound to the querystring value, not the route
    return View(Genres.All().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10);
  }
}
```